# RODBC + Shiny + Azure database how to pass dsn and password management

Tags: r, azure, passwords, shiny, rodbc

Two part question hopefully not TOO noobish:

I have an Azure db that I connect to from R on my windows machine. I can do that locally by using the "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" on odbcad32.exe, which gives me a named connection, with which I do: `c <- odbcConnect("my_DSN",uid="uid",pwd="pwd")`. This works fine.

I now want to upload my code to shinyapps so that it will refresh realtime (or at least once a day) for use in a dashboard. I'll use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680246/how-to-trigger-a-data-refresh-in-shiny) for ideas. Now my questions:

1) How do I pass the Azure information to "my_DSN" online? On my windows machine I use the driver odbcad32 to create a named connection, but how do I do that on shinyapps? None of the examples I've seen (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275144/r-shiny-rodbc-connection-failing) or [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/AyFthz3UGwg)) work on Azure. I need to specify the server/db/uid/pwd.

2) How do I pass my db password confidentially? If I put it in the Shiny code it's visible in the Shiny app, isn't it?

Comment: Are you using Shiny Open or Shiny Enterprise?

Comment: Shiny Open, does it make that big a difference?